What kind of threshold for storm door adjacent to exterior door & slatted porch
I'm a widow & have a problem with water pouring off bottom of storm door onto house. It's adjacent to exterior door which has a threshold but doesn't go under both doors. There was one under storm door, but a construction worker removed it & didn't replace. I've looked at a bunch of thresholds online & none look like the almost flat one I had with ridge at one edge. I need the threshold to meet the inner one & hang over cover edge of storm door storm door swings outward onto an unconnected porch.water drops between gaps between boards of porch onto house. Thanks for helping!

Deborah, it would help us greatly if you could post some pics of the storm door and the general area.

Interesting description, I still have no clue, so a photo would solve that
